# iredadmin directory was not found in the server

Tags: apache-2.4

I am getting a strange error with iRedAdmin and roundcube. After installing iRedAdmin, I checked sending mails etc. and everything worked fine. I recently changed the `SSL keys` and DirectoryRoot to `/var/www/public` it stops working and I get:

```
The requested URL /iredadmin was not found on this server.
```

How can I work around?

PS. I can login to roundcube email. But, email is not sent or received.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are trying to access it via https and not http?
I recently ecountered this problem after I installed Let's Encrypt.

I added this lines in the vhost file for SSL:

```
Alias /cluebringer "/usr/share/postfix-cluebringer-webui/webui/"
Alias /iredadmin/static "/opt/www/iredadmin/static/"
WSGIScriptAlias /iredadmin "/opt/www/iredadmin/iredadmin.py/"
Alias /mail "/opt/www/roundcubemail/"
Alias /awstats/icon "/usr/share/awstats/icon/"
Alias /awstatsicon "/usr/share/awstats/icon/"
ScriptAlias /awstats "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/"
```

And just reload the config.

(I compared the old vhost files which I took a backup from before the installation of Let's Encrypt and found out that thoose line was missing)

Answer (score 1):

If anyone has a similar issue where /iredadmin is showing not found after a proper install. open this file

```
nano /etc/apache2/conf-available/iredadmin.conf
```

uncomment the following lines

```
Alias /iredadmin/static "/opt/www/iredadmin/static/"
WSGIScriptAlias /iredadmin "/opt/www/iredadmin/iredadmin.py/"
```

Then do a sudo restart